# Close As Duplicate option for Area 51 Example Questions

Tags: feature-request, area-51

Currently, the flagging options for Example Questions on Area 51 are thus:

- Offensive, Abusive, or Hate Speech
- Spam
- Requires Moderator attention

I suggest adding one more: "Duplicate of existing question". In some cases, an Example Question being proposed is effectively the same as one that has already been asked on the same proposal. For these cases, I don't think it really adds value to count duplicates as separate questions towards meeting the proposal's goals.

The interface for this should be somewhat similar to the "Close as Duplicate" function for regular sites - the user provides a link to the duplicate or selects from a list of Example Questions that other users have already flagged as potential duplicates. Whether this should actually *function* the same - that is, whether a certain number of user votes should be used to validate a duplicate or not - may be a different issue entirely. Since there isn't yet a dedicated reputation system for that site's topic, closure of duplicates should probably be reserved for moderator validation.

In the end, this might just serve as a specialized version of the "Requires Moderator attention" flag. However, I don't believe the current interface makes it clear that this is a reason to flag a question for moderator attention.

And then maybe that's real question I should be asking - should we be flagging duplicate Example Questions at all, or does Area 51 just not care?

Comment: Users with enough reputation can vote to close questions. This requirement is much less than that of regular sites.

Comment: @gparyani On Area 51, "vote to close questions" refers to proposals I believe. Either way, I have enough rep for that privilege and I don't see a "vote to close" option on Example Questions.

Answer (score 1):

> In the end, this might just serve as a specialized version of the "Requires Moderator attention" flag.

It would. A basic reason would serve absolutely no purpose to a moderator because you'd need to explain which post it duplicates, which already requires free-form text anyways. So then you'd have to add a second option that also produces a free-form text box. It's easier to just type in the other box "duplicate of *x* example" and be done with it. You *really* don't need a separate option.

> And then maybe that's real question I should be asking - should we be flagging duplicate Example Questions at all, or does Area 51 just not care?

The purpose of duplicates on main sites is to direct the user to an answer elsewhere on the site. That doesn't apply on Area 51 because a) they're already on the same page and b) there are no answers on Area 51. That means there's no real purpose in *closing* a question as a duplicate there; the duplicate should just be deleted.

So yes, you should be flagging duplicates as the only purpose they serve is skewing the proposal's overall progress, which is a bad thing.

Comment: @animuson Could you edit your final paragraph? I think I get what you're saying - there's a distinction between *closing* duplicates and *deleting* duplicates (the former being what you do on a full site, the latter being what we want to do in A51 proposals) - but I'm not quite sure it's really clear.

Comment: @Iszi Is that more clear?